# How to configure multiple git accounts in Visual Studio Code workspace

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When switching between code-bases stored in different git repositories from different servers (for example Bitbucket and Github), I have sometimes committed code using the wrong user name.

Using Visual Studio Code, is there a way to set the values for `user.name` which are saved for a folder or workspace?

Comment: In `<WORKSPACE>/.git/config` you can set variables for individual cloned repositories. Also reachable via the normal `git config` CLI, just omit the `--global` switch

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having to do that for every repo? It would be great to "inherit" if the repos are cloned to the same location: everything in `/github/repos` uses usarA and everything in `/bitbucket/repos` uses userB

Comment: Not that I know.

Comment: Was this solved? Im looking to configure a Git user per workspace. instead of writing it per repo or via the global config

Answer (score 5):

Here are some ways to achieve your result.

### Git local config files

Open a terminal in the repo folder and use the commands:

- `git config --local user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"`
- `git config --local user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"`

Your new configs will appear in the file `<REPO_FOLDER>/.git/config`.

Now VSCode will override your global settings with the local ones.

*Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config*

### VSCode extensions

Otherways, if you want to directly modify the profile from inside VSCode these are 2 extensions which may help you:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.git-config-user-profiles
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stephtr.git-identity

### Scheduling idea

Another idea could be running a script from `taskschd.msc` every X time which checks all folders inside /Github or /Gitlab and assigns the relative profile to the config file.

Comment: The Git Config User profiles seems really useful, will use it so I can remember which Git account I'm using. +1